# Convert List of Objects to Tabular Structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-structures

I have a List of objects with this implementation:

```
 class Locations
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Dest { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to output a table, in CSV format, that has the Origins as rows, the Destinations as columns, and the Total where the specified Origins and Destinations meet. There could be an arbitrary number of Location objects in my List.

Given the following records in my List:

```
Origin=A
Dest=B
Total=10

Origin=B
Dest=A
Total=20
```

My output would look like this (with the '-' character meaning there's no Total between identical Origin/Destinations):

```
Origins/Destinations,A,B
A,-,10
B,20,-
```

Thus far, I have done the following:

1) Traverse the List to output the Destinations.

2) Traverse the List to output an Origin. For the Origin, traverse the list to find the Total for each Destination related to the Origin.

3) Repeat #2 for the next Origin.

My results aren't quite working out as the row/column data doesn't always match up. Is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: Can you give some example desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

After reading your update it seems that there's no need to sum as there is only going to be one object with a given `Origin` and `Destination`. In that case you can keep the code that collects `places`, do the nested `foreach` and simply get the total with

```
var item = locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Origin == origin && l.Dest == dest);
var total = item == null ? 0 : item.Total;
```

### Original answer

You can get a list of all locations with

```
var locations = new List<Locations>(); // assume it's populated
var places = locations.Select(l => l.Origin)
                      .Concat(locations.Select(l => l.Dest))
                      .Distinct()
                      .OrderBy(s => s); // why not sort it as well
```

At this point you can simply iterate over `places` for the rows and do another nested iteration for the columns:

```
foreach (var origin in places)
{
    foreach (var dest in places)
    {
        var total = locations.Where(l => l.Origin == origin && l.Dest == dest)
                             .Sum(l => l.Total);
    }
}
```

You can immediately see how you can easily construct a table with this structure. The main disadvantage of this approach is that it's doing a lot more work than strictly necessary; theoretically we can certainly iterate just once over `locations`, collecting the information as we go. It's possible to sum up the `Total` for each pair of `Origin` and `Dest` with

```
var totals = locations.GroupBy(l => new { l.Origin, l.Dest })
             .ToDictionary(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key.Origin, g.Key.Dest),
                           g => g.Sum(r => r.Total));
```

At this point we can take a page from the first solution:

```
foreach (var origin in places)
{
    foreach (var dest in places)
    {
        var total = totals[Tuple.Create(origin, dest)]; // almost too easy :)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understood your requirement correctly, but does this help?

```
var destinationGroups = locations
    .GroupBy(l=> l.Dest)
    .Select(grp => new{
        SumTotal = grp.Sum(l => l.Total),
        Destination = grp.Key ,
        CountOrigins = grp.Count()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be related with 2 dimensional matrix structure(It is known as **O/D matrix**), but the important thing is not to limit size. So, I would like to recommend you to build matrix structure using collection, to allow not to limit size. I put the code snippet as the following to show how to do. However, this code may be not optimal, but you could get some bright.

```cs
public class Location
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Dest { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Location other)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class ODMatrix
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> _origins = new HashSet<string>();
    private readonly HashSet<string> _dests = new HashSet<string>();
    private readonly Dictionary<Location, int> _values = new Dictionary<Location, int>();

    public int this[Location location]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_values.ContainsKey(location))
            {
                SetValue(location, 0);
            }
            return _values[location];
        }
        set { SetValue(location, value); }
    }

    private void SetValue(Location location, int value)
    {
        if (!_origins.Contains(location.Origin))
            _origins.Add(location.Origin);
        if (!_dests.Contains(location.Dest))
            _dests.Add(location.Dest);
        _values[location] = value;
    }

    public int this[string origin, string dest]
    {
        get { return this[new Location {Origin = origin, Dest = dest}]; }
        set { this[new Location {Origin = origin, Dest = dest}] = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var content = new StringBuilder();
        //print dest lables
        content.AppendLine(_dests.Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y));
        foreach (string origin in _origins)
        {
            //print origin lable
            content.Append(origin + ", ");
            foreach (string dest in _dests)
            {
                content.Append(this[origin, dest] + ", ");
            }
            content.Remove(content.Length - 2, 2);
            content.AppendLine();
        }
        return content.ToString();
    }
}
```

Oh, from your updated question, I checked out that you want to print the labels of the origin and dest. I think you could modify ToString method to show the content.

**[UPDATED]**
I updated the code to print the labels. This code was not tested so it may or may not have some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Group locations by origin
var table = 
    from location in list
    group location by location.Origin into originGroups
    select new {
        Origin = originGroups.Key
        Destinations = originGroups.ToDictionary(x => x.Dest)
    };

// Get list of destinations
var destinations = list.Select(location => location.Dest).Distinct();

// Output everything
foreach(var location in table)
    foreach(var dest in destinations)
        // output location.Destinations[dest].Total;
```